# Can Pavement ME Design be used to other areas besides USA and Canada?

Tags: highway-engineering, roadway

I live in Asia and would like to use Pavement ME Design for my research. Can the current version of ME Design be used for that? Please give me the answer.Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @jsotola Asians are a very polite society; and this is a "New contributor" for whom more experienced members are admonished to "Take care in . . . commenting."  Can you at least overlook the courteous words without labeling them as "just useless clutter"?

Comment: @SaowanitPrabnakorn my apologies for my choice of words ... I am just trying to point out that this is a Q&A site that has the purpose of answering questions ... there is no need to ask to have a question answered ... all you have to do, is to present the question

Answer (score 0):

There is a page of information online for this software that details the international licensing option.

https://www.aashtoware.org/products/pavement/pavement-ordering/

Scrolling down about halfway on the page reaches the following two sections of information that you may find relevant.

> **International License**
>
> AASHTOWare Pavement ME Design is available for licensing to entities
> located outside the United States and that do not have membership in
> AASHTO. These international entities must license through Applied
> Research Associates, Inc. (ARA), ARA can be reached at:
>
> Applied Research Associates, Inc. 
>  100 Trade Centre Drive, Suite
> 200
>  Champaign, IL 61820 
>  (217) 356-4500 
>  Fax: (217)
> 356-3088
>   Shobhit Mundra, email: smundra@ara.com
>
> **Educational Option**
>
> This is a no cost workstation version of the AASHTOWare Pavement ME
> Design software that is modified for use by educational institutions
> within the jurisdictions of our Member Departments, and/or Associate
> Members for teaching purposes in the classroom only. This option is
> not available to individuals and it is not to be used for research,
> graduate work or any other purpose. (An SI version is available for
> those institutions located within the jurisdictions of international
> AASHTO Member Departments.)
>
> The no cost educational version differs from the full version as
> follows:
>
> - Limited design types–new asphalt and concrete (JPCP and CRCP), AC/AC overlays, AC/JPCP overlays, unbonded PCC overlays;
> - Limited analysis period: 30 years;
> - Limited climate stations: 8 to 10 stations from around the country representing each climate zone;
> - No batch mode and sensitivity analysis;
> - Output reports (PDF and Excel) include the watermark text “Educational Version” and
> - No access to intermediate output files.
>
> Note: A licensing agreement executed by the institution assuring
> compliance with the education and training limitation is necessary to
> exercise the educational license option.
>
> The license agreement is between the institution and AASHTO.
> Therefore, the educational version of the software is limited to one
> copy per institution and should be used in a computer lab environment,
> installed on computers owned by the institution. It should not be
> installed on individual personal student machines.
>
> If the software is installed on multiple machines, the machines should
> be ghosted.
>
> Only one copy of the educational software is licensed to each
> institution and the maximum number of seats per institution is limited
> to 25.

If that international contact is insufficient to answer your question, you may try their main contact page at:

https://me-design.com/MEDesign/FAQs.html?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

This page details the requirements for the computer hardware to support the software as well.

**Conclusion**

It appears that an international accommodation is made by the company, and it is quite probable that this also includes a different price schedule.  You should contact them for further information.  If you are an educator at a university, the software may be available at no cost for educational purposes.